Automate Grafana Dashboard Creation
Currently I have created Grafana Dashboard manually. I have got the Json. I wanted to automate and I came across the Grafana HTTP API. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/dashboard/. The problem is currently Grafana is not exposed outside. Its having internal Load balancer. I am planning to automate the Dashboard creation throug

Create a short-lived service account token
Create a temporary pod(https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl) and execute the API calls by passing the json to create Dashboard from the pipeline.

Is there any alternatives or is there any security concern doing this ?

Currently, we dont have self hosted agent, so, here is what I did.

Create a shell script file(curl into creating the Dashboard calling the grafana api)
Create a Dashboard model Json
copy both into the pod while running through pipeline
execute the shell script on the pod through the pipeline.

Its working fine

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, there is no built-in task or extension task can create the Grafana Dashboard.
Therefore, using Grafana HTTP API to create Grafana Dashboard is a good choice and using short-lived service account token can also improve security.
Here is an example:
curl -X POST --insecure -H "Authorization: Bearer <serviceaccount token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "dashboard": {
    "id": null,
    "title": "Production Overview",
    "tags": [ "templated" ],
    "timezone": "browser",
    "rows": [
      {
      }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": 6,
    "version": 0
  },
  "overwrite": false
}' http://serverhost/api/dashboards/db

Since the Grafana is not exposed outside and have internal Load balancer, the limitation of this plan could be that when using the Microsoft-hosted agents in the Pipeline to execute the API through the temporary pod, it will not be able to access temp pod.
In this case, you can consider creating a self-hosted agent on a machine that has access to Grafana or on the machine with the same load balancer.
